# How to keep multiple Git submodules efficiently in sync

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am working on a multi-tier application where I have assigned a project folder for each service that I am building. The setup schematically looks like this:

```
.
├── ProjectA
│   ├── .git
│   ├── _framework
│   ├── backend
│   ├── config
│   ├── frontend
│   └── info
├── ProjectB
│   ├── .git
│   ├── _framework
│   ├── backend
│   ├── config
│   ├── frontend
│   └── info
└── ProjectC
    ├── .git
    ├── _framework
    ├── backend
    ├── config
    ├── frontend
    └── info
```

Within each project folder, I have a configured a submodule in the `_framework` folder.
As I am actively developing in each of the folders, I am also making frequent changes in the `_framework` folder. I am finding that keeping the `_framework` submodule in sync across all projects is taking up a lot of time.

For example:
When I am developing in `ProjectB` and make a change in the submodule, I will commit and push my changes to the remote repository. Then when I switch to `ProjectC`, I will first need to pull the `_framework` submodule, commit the changes in the main GIT repository before I am able to start working again.

I understand that there are good reasons for why GIT submodules are setup like that, but is there any way to automate the process? So that when I am working in ProjectB and I push the submodule - that in the other projects that same submodule is automatically pulled and committed in the main local GIT repro?

Comment: Technically you could automate by setting up a post-push hook in every project so that every time when you push, it'll run a pull-and-commit in all other projects. It sounds like over-complicating things though.

Comment: @jingx: How would this work? How would the ProjectA and ProjectC Git repositories "know" that they need to run a pull-and-commit action when I have updated, committed and pushed the submodule in ProjectB?

Comment: The script would need to know about all other projects. It also knows in which project it's running, so it just needs to go to other projects and pull there. Yeah, that's also why I said it was over-complicating things...

Comment: Another thought - have you considered solving this problem with the dependency management in your build tool, rather than git?

Comment: @jingx: No, I have no experience with those to be honest. Was hoping for a Git-only solution to be language independent. But maybe for now, a dependancy management approach/tool might work. These are all DotNet Core applications: anything that you can recommend?

Comment: Sorry can't help you there... not familiar with the .Net eco-system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the suggestion from @jingx, I decided to make a pre-push hook in the git repositories of `ProjectA`, `ProjectB`, `ProjectC`. The pre-push hook seemed a logical event to use since you have to push the new state of the submodules in the main repository anyway when you have changed and successfully tested the code in the Git submodule.

As a reference on Git hooks, I used this excellent explanation from Atlassian: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks

Because I am more familiar with JavaScript than with Bash scripting, I decided to create a NodeJS script that would be executed as the pre-push hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node


const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('util');


// Logging something to the console so that we can verify if the hook is triggered or not
console.log('Invoking pre-push hook v1.0');

// Global variables
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const gitRepositoryPathOs = process.argv[1].replace(/(.*)\/\.git\/.*/, '$1');
const gitRepositoryParentFolder = path.dirname(gitRepositoryPathOs);
const gitRepositoryFolderName = path.basename(gitRepositoryPathOs);
const scriptFilePathOs = __filename;
const scriptLogFolderPathOs = `${path.dirname(scriptFilePathOs)}/logs`;

const pushSiblingProjects = false;
const debugRoutine = true;
let debugInfo = "";
let stdIn = [];

// Defines all the project folder names where this hook should be working with
const projectFolderNames = ['ProjectA', 'ProjectB', 'ProjectC'];
// Defines the submodules that this routine should be checking for in each project folder
const submodulePaths = ['_framework'];



/**
 * Executes a shell command
 * 
 * @param {string} cmd Shell command to execute
 * @param {string} [workingDirectory=gitRepositoryParentFolder] Directory to execute the shell command in
 * @returns The result of the shell command
 */
const executeShellCommand = async (cmd, workingDirectory = gitRepositoryPathOs) => {
    // if (debugRoutine) debugInfo += `- executeShellCommand('${cmd}', '${workingDirectory}')\n`;
    const {stdout, stderr} = await exec(cmd, {
        cwd: workingDirectory
    });

    return stdout;
}

/**
 * Starts the logic of this GIT hook routine
 * 
 * @returns Exit code to indicate to the GIT process if it should continue or not
 */
const initGitHookRoutine = async () => {
    // Global variables
    let shellCommand = '';
    let shellResult = '';
    let siblingGitRepositoryUpdateExecuted = false;

    // Catch all parameters passed to the process.argv
    debugInfo += "Passed arguments:\n\n";
    process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
        debugInfo += `${index}: ${val}\n`;
    });

    debugInfo += `Standard In:\n${stdIn.join()}`;

    debugInfo += "\n\n";
    debugInfo += `- gitRepositoryPathOs: '${gitRepositoryPathOs}'\n`;
    debugInfo += `- gitRepositoryParentFolder: '${gitRepositoryParentFolder}'\n`;
    debugInfo += `- gitRepositoryFolderName: '${gitRepositoryFolderName}'\n`;
    debugInfo += `- scriptFilePathOs: '${scriptFilePathOs}'\n`;


    try {
        // Retrieve a list of objects that we are about to push to the remote repository
        shellCommand = `git diff --stat --cached origin/master`;
        shellResult = await executeShellCommand(shellCommand);
    } catch (err) {
        shellResult = `ERROR: could not execute '${shellCommand}', error details: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
    }
    debugInfo += `- shellCommand: '${shellCommand}', shellResult: '${shellResult}'\n`;

    // Mark which submodules we need to process
    let submodulePathsToProcess = [];
    submodulePaths.forEach((submodulePath) => {
        if (shellResult.indexOf(submodulePath) > -1) {
            submodulePathsToProcess.push(submodulePath);
        }
    })
    debugInfo += `- submodulePathsToProcess: ${submodulePathsToProcess.join()}\n`;


    if (submodulePathsToProcess.length > 0) {
        let submodulePath = '';

        // Now loop through the other projects and update the submodules there 
        // Using "old fashioned loop style" here as it seems to work better with async function calls...
        for (let i = 0; i < projectFolderNames.length; i++) {
            const projectFolderName = projectFolderNames[i];

            if (projectFolderName !== gitRepositoryFolderName) {
                const siblingGitRepositoryPathOs = `${gitRepositoryParentFolder}/${projectFolderName}`;
                debugInfo += `- processing GIT repository '${siblingGitRepositoryPathOs}'\n`;

                // Loop through the submodules that we need to update
                for (let j = 0; j < submodulePathsToProcess.length; j++) {
                    submodulePath = submodulePathsToProcess[j];

                    const siblingGitRepositorySubmodulePathOs = `${siblingGitRepositoryPathOs}/${submodulePath}`;
                    debugInfo += `- processing GIT submodule '${siblingGitRepositorySubmodulePathOs}'\n`;

                    try {
                        // Pull the latest version of the submodule from the remote repository
                        shellCommand = `git pull origin master`;
                        shellResult = await executeShellCommand(shellCommand, siblingGitRepositorySubmodulePathOs);
                    } catch (err) {
                        shellResult = `ERROR: could not execute '${shellCommand}', error details: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
                    }
                    debugInfo += `- shellCommand: '${shellCommand}', shellResult: '${shellResult}'\n`;
                }

                // Use git status to check which submodules need to be committed
                try {
                    shellCommand = `git status`;
                    shellResult = await executeShellCommand(shellCommand, siblingGitRepositoryPathOs);
                } catch (err) {
                    shellResult = `ERROR: could not execute '${shellCommand}', error details: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
                }
                debugInfo += `- shellCommand: '${shellCommand}', shellResult: '${shellResult}'\n`;

                // Now check for each submodule if it needs to be committed to the sibling project repository
                for (let j = 0; j < submodulePathsToProcess.length; j++) {
                    submodulePath = submodulePathsToProcess[j];

                    if (shellResult.indexOf(`${submodulePath} (new commits)`) > -1) {
                        // 1) Add the submodule reference to the local git staging area
                        try {
                            shellCommand = `git add ${submodulePath}`;
                            shellResult = await executeShellCommand(shellCommand, siblingGitRepositoryPathOs);
                        } catch (err) {
                            shellResult = `ERROR: could not execute '${shellCommand}', error details: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
                        }
                        debugInfo += `- shellCommand: '${shellCommand}', shellResult: '${shellResult}'\n`;

                        // 2) Commit the submodule reference to the local git repository
                        if (shellResult.indexOf('ERROR') === -1) {
                            siblingGitRepositoryUpdateExecuted = true;
                            try {
                                shellCommand = `git commit -m "Submodule ${path.basename(submodulePath)} updated by GIT hook utility"`;
                                shellResult = await executeShellCommand(shellCommand, siblingGitRepositoryPathOs);
                            } catch (err) {
                                shellResult = `ERROR: could not execute '${shellCommand}', error details: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
                            }
                            debugInfo += `- shellCommand: '${shellCommand}', shellResult: '${shellResult}'\n`;
                        }

                        // 3) Optionally push this to the remote repository (not recommended)
                        if (pushSiblingProjects) {
                            if (shellResult.indexOf('ERROR') === -1) {
                                try {
                                    shellCommand = `git push origin master`;
                                    shellResult = await executeShellCommand(shellCommand, siblingGitRepositoryPathOs);
                                } catch (err) {
                                    shellResult = `ERROR: could not execute '${shellCommand}', error details: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
                                }
                                debugInfo += `- shellCommand: '${shellCommand}', shellResult: '${shellResult}'\n`;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }

        // Check if we need to execute anything after we have modified the sibling repositories
        if (siblingGitRepositoryUpdateExecuted) {
            // Put your logic in here
        }

    }

    // Dump the debug information to the console
    if (debugRoutine) console.log(`* debugInfo: ${debugInfo}`);

    // Dump the debug information in a log file so that we can inspect it later on
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(`${scriptLogFolderPathOs}/pre-push.log`, debugInfo);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`ERROR: write the log file in folder '${scriptLogFolderPathOs}', error details: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    }

    // To avoid push from taking place exit a code > 0
    return process.exit(0);
};


/** 
 * This is where the execution starts
 * First we capture the content from the shell standard in and then we start the logic itself
*/

// NOTE: use 'npm install split --save-dev' to install the split module
process.stdin.pipe(require('split')()).on('data', (line) => {
    // Push the line into the stdIn array so we can use it later on
    if (line.trim() !== '') stdIn.push(line);
}).on('end', initGitHookRoutine)
```

The NodeJS script requires one external module ('split') for parsing standard-in from the shell command that the Git hook will add when calling the script.
The code is still a bit rough, but I thought this would be enough for others to extend.

In order to get the NodeJS script to work, you need to set the file permissions on the NodeJS script to include execute (see the Atlassian page).

On my Mac, the script refused to run because the hashbang `#!/usr/bin/env node` refused to get executed. I managed to solve this by creating a symlink to the node executable using `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node`

On my machine I first had to disable System Integrity Protection, before I could actually create the symlink. More info here: 
https://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away

Comment: Interesting approach. +1. I still prefer mine. Don't forget anyone cloning the repo will have to install the hook.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to reference `_framework`:

- as a submodule in your main project (at the same level than projects A, B and C)
- as a symlink in each subproject (`-> ../framework_`)

That way, only the main project has to keep track of `framework_` version.

Comment: That is an interesting thought! This approach would not skew up the integrity of the main repositories (ProjectA, ProjectB, ..)?

Comment: @Guppie70 No, but those projects would depend on the main project in order to keep track of which version of framework_ they are using.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is not working. After moving the submodules source files to a new location and creating the alias using `ln -s /new/location/of/submodule/_framework /ProjectA/_framework`, the main repository does not recognize the submodule anymore. `git status` in the main repository returns `fatal: Not a git repository: _framework/../.git/modules/_framework`. Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: @Guppie70 no need for moving: add a submodule framework_ in the main repo, and delete the one in each project. Then add your symlinks

Comment: The downside of that approach is that when somebody else would be cloning the sub-projects, the submodules won't be there and the application/service would not compile...

Comment: @Guppie70 Agreed: an initialization step is needed